# Rolling back to a previous migration in django

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I used my django migrations to migrate my database. One of the migrations was data migrations. But I made a mistake: I didn't save the model). Thus, no change was applied to data. I corrected the .py file that executed the python code for the data migrations. I now want to re-execute it. Is there a way to rollback to the previous version of my database or just running

```
./manage.py migrate my_app 0004
```

with 0004 being the file that did the datamigrations does the trick?

Comment: That exact syntax should work. What happens when you try?

Comment: It said that nothing was there to migrate.

Answer (score 32):

In order to rollback I had to do the following

1. `showmigrations` to see where I am
2. `migrate 0003` (to go one step back)
3. `showmigrations` to verify that it worked and I am one version behind
4. `migrate 0004` to migrate correctly

Comment: nowadays I believe `migrate -l` is `showmigrations`